# Why after clicking the icon, the original background is not replaced and does not appear? In visual studio(not visual studio code)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a vertical slider in visual studio (not visual studio code), which after clicking a description will appear and the background image will be changed. But when clicked the background image is not changed, what should I fix?
In visual studio code, background image change after click the icon
[image: Vscode]
[image: vscode after click]
But in Visual studio, background image not change after click the icon
[image: vs]
[image: vs after click]

```
<div class="feature">
<div class="background">
 <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper text-center">
      <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="~/">
            <ul>
                <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/eat.png">
                   <p>Eat and Come</p>
              <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
                <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              </div>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="~/assets/Image/b2.jpg">
               <ul>
                    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/grab.png">
                     <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
                <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
                  <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
              </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="s">
               <ul>
                <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/sale.png">
                 <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
            <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
              <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
        <ul>
        <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/Secret sale.png">
         <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
        <ul>
        <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/experience.png">
         <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
        <ul>
        <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/auction.png">
         <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide text-center sg-feature" data-bg="https://i.imgur.com/cqAklTF.jpeg">
        <ul>
        <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="~/assets/Image/loyalty.png">
         <h3>Eat and Come</h3>
    <div class="sg-feature-desc hidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
      <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

```
.feature {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.background {
    background-image: url('../Image/b1.jpg');
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 625px;
    width: 100%;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;

}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

    .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

.center .slick-center h3 {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
    -o-transform: scale(1.08);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
    color: #e67e22;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.08);
}

.center h3 {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.sg-feature img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 7,
    direction: "vertical",
    autoHeight: true,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
});

let $slidesDescriptions = $('.sg-feature-desc');
$(document).on('click', '.sg-feature', function () {
    $slidesDescriptions.addClass('hidden');

    let $slide = $(this);
    console.log($slide.data('bg'));
    $slide.find('.sg-feature-desc').removeClass('hidden');
    $('background').css('background-image', `url('${$slide.data('bg')}')`);

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by visual studio? You mean you created a webpage?

Comment: yup, first i make in vs code, but i change to asp.net in visual studio